# How to un-filter or clear filters in r dplyr?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

A diagram showing what I am trying to achieve:

[image: A diagram showing what I am trying to achieve:]

Hello community. I am trying to mutate a new variable depending on the mean function of one specific  group (filtered and grouped). As I try to create the new variable I ungroup the set to operate in all groups. I tried running **this R code**. 
However, the mutate function applies only to the filtered group and can't find an un-filter function. I dput() a sample of my data frame below **(df01)**. Thank you very much in advance for all your comments and suggestions. Regards. M.

**R code**:

```
df01 %>% #summary table of the means to be used. 
  filter(GFPimg == "WT") %>% 
  group_by(Demineralization, Cond, Temp) %>%  
  summarise(Mean2 = mean(Mean)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Demineralization))
  print() 

df01 %>%
  filter(GFPimg == "WT") %>% 
  group_by(Demineralization, Cond, Temp) %>% 
  mutate(mean2 = mean(Mean)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Demineralization, Cond)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Demineralization, Cond) %>%
  mutate(submean = Mean - mean2) %>% 
  print(n=200)
```

### **Data frame sample df01**:

```
df01 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54), 
GFPimg = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("HT", "MT", "WT"), class = "factor"), 
Cond = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("EC", "EI"), class = "factor"), 
Temp = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("37c", "RT"), class = "factor"), 
Side = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("L", "R"), class = "factor"), 
Mean = c(62.435, 64.537, 102.447, 92.608, 103.277, 104.711, 67.017, 61.748, 68.921, 59.962, 63.368, 60.435, 69.54, 67.886, 51.71, 50.291, 50.881, 54.865, 80.538, 84.05, 92.223, 87.337, 90.444, 90.728, 29.951, 28.574, 30.896, 30.399, 29.773, 30.715, 31.498, 30.385, 99.004, 83.644, 95.962, 83.451, 22.649, 22.5, 53.066, 51.368, 55.459, 57.203, 54.444, 58.504, 76.518, 95.81, 23.43, 24.736, 28.86, 28.347, 28.386, 29.319, 58.017, 63.064, 80.293, 89.194, 70.52, 63.989, 71.436, 59.379, 75.986, 80.22, 71.583, 76.589, 77.138, 95.998, 77.193, 71.384, 75.614, 83.061, 73.062, 71.833, 71.83, 55.783, 77.376, 64, 96.14, 99.876, 40.972, 53.465, 36.25, 47.626, 40.619, 39.697, 34.34, 36.855, 77.131, 75.35, 67.014, 58.811, 39.237, 49.357, 74.333, 79.921, 62.631, 63.119, 60.207, 65.171, 77.563, 82.078, 39.115, 45.988, 42.65, 55.806, 33.534, 41.271, 62.359, 67.092), 
Demineralization = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("After", "Before"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -108L))
```

---

Comment: R is not like Excel where you click on filter and then later unclick it. What the pipe operator (%>%) does is pass on one modified dataframe from the previous operation to the next one. When you do a subset() you are effectively producing a new dataframe that keeps only those rows that satisfy the condition, and drops all other rows. If you must keep previous rows then you must save intermediate results in other variables. Also it might be a good idea to use ifelse() to select only those values that match your condition to calculate mean(), instead of using subset() in this case.

Comment: @user2332849, where is `subset()` coming into the question? I don't see it ...

Comment: @ user2332849. Thank you very much for your comment.  So instead of filter() I should use ifelse() or is a combination of subset() and ifelse()...?

Comment: Sorry subset() does the filtering like the function filter().

Comment: If you use subset() or filter(), all those records that do not match the condition will be dropped for good. If wanna keep them and just perform a calculation on another specific subset, you can apply a conditional with ifelse().
Ex: mean(ifelse(GFPimg == 'WT', Mean, NA), na.rm=T)
This will replace all values where GFPimg is not 'WT' with NA's, which will then be dropped before the mean is calculated.

Comment: @ user2332849. Thank you very much I will try that.

Comment: If you skip the filter step and do `summarise(Mean2 = mean(Mean[GFPimg=="WT"]))` does that give you the result you were hoping for?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you don't need the line "group_by(Demineralization, Cond) %>%". You're not doing a summarising after it, or any mutation that depends on the data being organized by groups.

Comment: Thanks to @user2332849 and @eipi10, `mutate(Mean2 = mean(ifelse(GFPimg == 'WT', Mean, NA), na.rm=T))` solved my problem.

Comment: @Marcello Anytime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since other users might have a similar question, I post the answer I arrived to.

**Lessons learned:**

1. The pipe operator (%>%) pass on a modified dataframe from the
   previous operation to the next one.
2. Subset() and filter() effectively produce a new dataframe that keeps
   only those rows that satisfy the condition, and drops all other
   rows.
3. There is no function to un-filter or clear filters or un-subset in dplyr. Instead, to keep all rows and perform a calculation on another specific
   subset, you can apply a conditional with ifelse().

**Code that solved my problem**:

```
df01 %>%
  group_by(Demineralization, Cond, Temp) %>% 
  mutate(Mean2 = mean(ifelse(GFPimg == 'WT', Mean, NA), na.rm=T)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(submean = Mean - Mean2) %>% 
  print(n=200)
```